# Spring MVC Binding collection of interfaces

Tags: spring-mvc

I try to bind a list of interfaces to a controller and to be able to edit them in a JSP form.
i have created a list like this:

```
private List<MyInterface> list = new AutoPopulatingList<MyInterface>(MyInterface.class);
```

i have no problem populate the list and send it to the JSP, on the JSP i use spring form tags like so:

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="entry" varStatus="i">
    <form:input path="list[${i.index]" />
</c:forEach>
```

so far all is well, my problem is when i submit the form.
each element in my list can be of a different implementation of the interface, the interface does expose a type property.

I want a way to tell Spring when creating an instance of an element in the list to look at the appropriate type field and create the correct implementation.